# Fragmentation and recvfrom function

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

If my UDP message is fragmented to the several IP packets, will it come to the server as one single datagram (already combined again) returned from `recvfrom` function (for example, in Python, but I think that it should be the same in all BSD-based socket implementations) or should I combine it by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, transport layer knows nothing about fragmentation, so you don't need to care about fragmentation.

> When an IP datagram is fragmented, it is not reassembled until it reaches its final destination. (This handling of reassembly differs from some other networking protocols that require reassembly to take place at the next hop, not at the final destination.) The IP layer at the destination performs the reassembly.

Please, consider the following article to get more info (paragraph 11.5):
http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/udp_user.htm